# How do I create an Entity with Multiple Navigation Properties to the same Table?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

This question has been asked in a few variations, but I believe that my issue is somewhat unique.

I'm using the database-first approach with Entity Framework 4, and I am trying to map and `Account` to multiple `Addresses`, as well as map that same account to `BillingAddress` and `ShippingAddress`.

Here is my db schema:
Account

- ID
- BillingAddressID
- ShippingAddressID

Address

- ID
- AccountID

I have 3 foreign keys.

1. `Account.BillingAddressID` to `Address.ID`
2. `Account.ShippingAddressID` to `Address.ID`
3. `Address.ID` to `Account.ID`

I would like to have the following POCO setup:

```
public class Account {

    public int ID { get; set; }        

    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address {

    public int ID { get; set; }        

    public int AccountID { get; set; }
}
```

Yet when I do this and try to create a new Account with an address, I get the following error:

"An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships."

One thought I had was to shift the schema to a full many-to-many relationship between Account and Address. Then I guess I could put the Billing vs. Shipping vs. Other in the AccountAddresses table and use that in the foreign keys, but I am really curious if I can get it to work as is.

```
Account a = new Account();
// snip: add some account properties

Account.Addresses.Add(new Address {
    // snip: some properties here
});

context.SaveChanges();

==> ERROR (as mentioned above)
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: "*when I do this and try to create a new Account with an address*": Can you show the code or describe this more precisely? A new address or an address which already exists? Which of the three navigation properties from `Account` to `Address` do you set? All, some, one? With the same address or different addresses? Etc.

Comment: @Slauma I've added some sample code for how I am trying to use this.

Comment: Did you create the database or did you let EF create the database for you? If you created teh DB first and then created your POCO's, you are going to have to use the fluent mapping API to tell EF how you want to map your Entities to SQL Tables. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295844%28v=VS.103%29.aspx